# Minimum value of $\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\gamma$

Tags: calculus

> If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be a variable and $k$ be a constant such that $a\tan\alpha+b\tan\beta+c\tan\gamma=k$.Then find minimum value of $\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\gamma$ is

Try: Using Cauchy Schwarz Inequality:

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\gamma)\geq (a\tan\alpha+b\tan\beta+c\tan\gamma)^2$

So we have $$\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta+\tan^2\gamma)\geq \frac{k^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

Could some help me to solve it without Cauchy Schwarz Inequity .

Please explain, thanks

Comment: Why they have to be tangents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=\tan^2 x + \tan^2 y+\tan^2 z\\
g(x,y,z)&=a\tan x +b\tan y+c\tan z=k
\end{align}
We want to find the minimum of $f$ constrained to $g$, and we can apply Lagrange Multiplier. Consider the equation $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$. Since
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y,z)&=(2\tan x\sec^2 x, 2\tan y\sec^2 y, 2\tan z\sec^2 z),\\
\nabla g(x,y,z)&=(a\sec^2 x, b\sec^2 y,c\sec^2 z),
\end{align}
for a root of the equation $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$, this equation holds:
$$\begin{cases}\tag 1
2\tan x^*=\lambda a\\
2\tan y^*=\lambda b\\
2\tan z^*=\lambda c
\end{cases}$$
Substitite (1) into $g(x,y,z)=k$, then $\lambda=\dfrac{2k}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ and
$$
f(x^*,y^*,z^*)=\frac{\lambda^2 (a^2+b^2+c^2)}{4}=\frac{k^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.
$$
This is what we want.

Comment: Can you suggest good readings for lagrange multiplier, only know calculus 1.

Comment: @KingTut Any Calculus 2 textbooks may contain Lagrange multiplier.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of Geometry.

$x=\tan \alpha$; $ y= \tan \beta$; $z=\tan \gamma$.

Plane: $ax+by +cz=k.$

$d^2 := x^2+y^2+z^2$ is the squared distance from the origin to a point $(x,y,z)$.

Need to find the (perpendicular= minimal) distance of the  plane from the origin.

$\vec n = \dfrac{1}{a^2+b^2+c^2}(a,b,c)$ is the unit normal of the plane.

$\vec r(t) = t \vec n.$

Plane:

$\vec n\cdot(\vec r(t) -\vec r_0)=0.$

Choose: $\vec r_0 = (0,0,k/c).$

Find $t:$

$\vec n \cdot (t\vec n -\vec r_0)=0$, or

$t - \vec n \cdot \vec r_0=0.$

Hence:

$t= \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$

Since $\vec n$ is a unit vector $t$ is the distance from the origin to the plane .

We are looking for the squared distance:

$t^2 = \dfrac{k^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$